# Why do I get a certificate error on Ubuntu but not on Windows?

Tags: java, ssl

In a java application, I'm trying to read an RSS feed from google alerts (https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/...).  On my laptop, running Windows 10, it works fine.  Visiting the URL of the RSS feed also works fine from a web browser on Windows.  But when I try running the java application on an Ubuntu server (16.04.06) I get the following exception:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building       failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification   path to requested target`

I can work around this by finding the certificate that my web browser trusts and storing it in the trust store than my java application is using on the Ubuntu server.  However, this doesn't seem like the right solution.  I think this is a root certificate that should be trusted by the operating system.  In my web browser it is described as "GlobalSign Root CA - R2."  When I run the java application on my Windows 10 laptop it is somehow finding a certificate that it trusts.  This leads me to believe that the certificates on my Ubuntu server are out of date, or something.

It there a better or more proper way of solving this problem than storing the certificate I found in my web browser in the java application's trust store on the Ubuntu server?

Comment: Probably. First, which version of java did you install on Ubuntu? And have you upgraded ubuntu since installation?

Comment: I'm using openjdk version "1.8.0_242".  I also tried Oracle's 1.8.0_242.  Just updated all of the packages on Ubuntu today.

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`

Comment: apt-get dist-upgrade and apt-get install ca-certificates didn't make any changes.  I ran apt-get update earlier today so maybe everything was already up to date.  That did not solve the problem.

Comment: Oh well. Try [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), or upgrade to a different JDK. Sorry that did not solve the problem. Do you have a proxy on the ubuntu side? Other than that, I can't think of anything for you to try.

Comment: Are root CA certificates part of the JDK?

Comment: First Google result: https://superuser.com/questions/55470/which-trusted-root-certificates-are-included-in-java